# Website popout page design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to have 4 boxes that can be clicked and pop out with text and can scroll.
Similar to the projects page here: http://www.visionslighting.com
However i would like it to be in html/javascript or similar instead of flash.

i have found this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagemagnify.htm
which is exactly what i want only with images.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with the [jquery-ui](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).  They have a function called dialog that you can tell to be a modal(the box that floats on the screen).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a javascript lightbox. Check out this one: http://defunkt.io/facebox/

You can find even more here: http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts